# Get describe-key links to bring me to org-mode config files, not .el config files?

Tags: init-file, org-babel, config, literate-programming

For my Emacs configuration, I use a literate programming setup. My config files are in org-mode format, and my `init.el` file consists mostly of `org-babel` lines like `(org-babel-load-file "~/emacs/startup.org")`.

I often use `describe-key` to look up custom functions I have created in order to edit them. However, `describe-key` gives me something like:

```
M-s-g runs the command gnugol, which is an interactive Lisp function in `startup.el'.
```

in which `startup.el` is a link to that file. However in my case, startup.el is a file that's automatically generated (tangled?) every time I launch Emacs, so any edits I make to it will get overwritten.

How do I tell `describe-key` to instead give me a link directly to `startup.org` (or whatever config file contains the defun) so I can edit my actual config files?

Comment: If you don't mind a multistep solution, you could add `:comments` header which will add commented links back to `startup.org` file when tangling `startup.el`. Then when `describe-key` takes you to `startup.el`, you should be able to use `org-babel-tangle-jump-to-org` to jump back to `startup.org`. I'm sure someone will post a better solution, so I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: Here's [`:comments`](http://orgmode.org/manual/comments.html) header info.

Comment: That page of the manual doesn't have examples of the syntax. Can you give me an idea of what it would look like to add a link to the file in the comments header?

Comment: `org-mode` should add the links automatically when tangling a file from a code block with `:comments noweb` header. Adding `#+HEADER: :comments noweb` line directly above `#+BEGIN_SRC:` line should work. Then tangle the file with`C-c C-v t`. When you open the new file in emacs, you should see extra comments in the source code which contain a link back to the original org file.

Comment: After new comments have been added, you should be able to jump back org file by putting cursor on a the linked comments link and doing 'M-x org-babel-tangle-jump-to-org`. It's been a while since I tried it but think that's how it worked.

Comment: I see. Now that I've tried it, I agree that it requires kind of a lot of steps in order to get to the relevant function in my org file.

Comment: I add [header variables](http://orgmode.org/manual/tangle_002dmode.html#tangle_002dmode) so that my tangled files are read only `:tangle-mode (identity #o444)`, read only files are opened in view-mode `view-read-only`  and also use the `:comments both` option combined with an intro explaining `org-babel-jump-to-org`